# MongoDB aggregation - finding duplicates

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to learn how to better write MongoDB queries, but I'm getting stuck looking at the docs and trying to figure out how to structure a query that would provide the data I'm looking for here.

I have a collection called `customers`, containing the following fields:

```
_id,
companyId,
name
```

I'd like to write a query that returns the customers that have the same `companyId` and `name`.

For example, if my collection included:

| _id | companyId | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | companyId1 | John |
| id2 | companyId2 | Bob |
| id3 | companyId1 | John |

I'd like to get query results of

| _id | companyId | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | companyId1 | John |
| id3 | companyId1 | John |

Or results containing just this would be sufficient:

| companyId | name |
| --- | --- |
| companyId1 | John |

I've been checking the docs but not sure I'm getting how find matches for these fields. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$group` with `$sum` to get count per group. `$match` with count > 1.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        companyId: "$companyId",
        name: "$name"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      count: {
        $gt: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$_id"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P-rpZkoRrLN)

Comment: Thank you! And that Mongo Playground link is awesome. Very much appreciated!